# I'm trying to a create a program that draws lines between clicks, but when I click my mouse button, nothing happens

Tags: python

Basically the program is a simple thing where I'm trying to create a line between two mouseclicks, but when I click, nothing seems to happen. I don't get any errors, or nothing, when I click my mouse.

When I tried looking it up online, I saw people writing art.bind('', draw_line) as either <'Button-1'> or <'ButtonPress-1'> and I'm not sure if either makes a difference.

```
import tkinter as tk

art = tk.Tk()

art.geometry("700x300")

def draw_line(event):
    global click_number
    global x1,y1
    if click_number==0:
        x1=event.x
        y1=event.y
        click_number=1
    else:
        x2=event.x
        y2=event.y
        canvas.create_line(x1,y1,x2,y2,fill='black',width=10)

canvas = tk.Canvas(art, width=700, height=3)
canvas.pack()
canvas.old_coords = None
art.bind('<Button-1>', draw_line)
click_number=0

art.mainloop()
```

Honestly, I tried researching Google, tried looking at other example codes of similar projects, tried implementing those into my program, but nothing is happening

Comment: The problem is `height=3` for the canvas. It works as expected with `height=300`

Answer (score 0):

Two problems:

1. Canvas height should be 300 not 3.  You could only see the drawing in the top 3 pixels.  Changing the background color of the Canvas (e.g. `bg='green'`) would've made it more obvious.
2. Add `click_number = 0` to the `else:`; otherwise, later clicks always start at the first click's position.

Comment: I cant believe I missed that haha! Thanks for the help :D

Answer (score 0):

The issue is related to the order of operations and the use of the global variable click_number
[image]

```
    import tkinter as tk
    
    art = tk.Tk()
    art.geometry("700x300")
    
    def draw_line(event):
        global click_number, x1, y1
    
        if click_number == 0:
            x1 = event.x
            y1 = event.y
            click_number = 1
        else:
            x2 = event.x
            y2 = event.y
            canvas.create_line(x1, y1, x2, y2, fill='black', width=2)
            click_number = 0
    
    canvas = tk.Canvas(art, width=700, height=300)
    canvas.pack()
    canvas.old_coords = None
    
    click_number = 0
    x1, y1 = 0, 0
    
    art.bind('<Button-1>', draw_line)
    
    art.mainloop()


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1qGRe.png
```